# Ember can't get data from hasMany relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I try to build Rails+Ember app using Ember data.

Model:

```js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    content: DS.attr('string'),
    image_before: DS.attr('string'),
    created_at: DS.attr('date'),
    updated_at: DS.attr('date'),
    status: DS.attr('number'),
    comments: DS.hasMany('comment', {async: true}),
    user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
});
```

and get json like this (json is generated with active_model_serializers)

```js
    {"work":{
            "id":3,  
            "user_id":1, 
            "content":"My first photo", 
            "image_before": "image_before/original/AnViWyuup5I.png", 
            "created_at":"2015-08-11T16:57:24.153Z", 
            "updated_at":"2015-11-13T11:39:44.076Z", 
            "status":1, 
            "comment_ids":[13]
    },
    "comments": [{
        "id": 13, 
        "text": "good!", 
        "created_at": "2015-09-28T10:34:16.461Z", 
        "user_id": 2
    }]
}
```

Template is:

```html
<div class="work__img-wrapper">
    <img class="work__img" src="{{model.image_before}}">
</div>
<div class="work__content">{{model.content}}</div>

<div class="work__comments-list">
        <strong>Comments( {{model.comments.length}} ):</strong>
        {{#each model.comments as |comment|}}
            <div class="work__comment">
                <div class="work__comment-text">{{comment.text}}</div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
</div>
```

At page, I get all information about work and Comments( 0 ), but Ember Inspector at Chrome shows comment.

How i can print comments too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. By default, DS.hasMany associated IDs are not added to the objects that are serialized (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html).

Should add

```js
export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer
    .extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin)
    .extend({
    attrs: {
        comments: {serialize: 'ids', deserialize: 'ids'}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model definition should read:

```
comments: DS.hasMany('comment', {async: false}),
```

because the related data is being side-loaded with the response, not being fetched asynchronously.
If this is an Ember 2.0 application, the default async setting is `true`. From the Ember Blog (http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html, emphasis mine):

> In Ember Data 2.0 relationships will be asynchronous by default. Sync
>   relationships will still be supported but you will need to manually
>   opt into them by setting **{ async: false }** on your relationships. Ember
>   Data 1.13 will log a deprecation warning you if you have any
>   relationships where the async property is not explicitly set.
>   Additionally you can use ember-watson to help identify cases in your
>   codebase where you have relationships without an explicit async
>   property.

Comment: Ah, I misread your question - I missed the Active Model portion (edit: I don't have enough reputation cred to comment on the selected answer)